# Regex: How to validate the string whether it contains the following pattern in angular 6

Tags: angular, regex, validation

```
urn:epc:id:sgln:345344423.1345.143
```

I want to validate the above string from the text box whether it is in the above format with the exact string like (urn:epc:id:sgln) then followed by numbers with two dot separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern: `urn:epc:id:sgln:\d+\.\d+\.\d+`

Pattern explanation:

`urn:epc:id:sgln:` - match `urn:epc:id:sgln:` literally

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`\.` - match dot (.) literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kc4H7a/1)

Answer (score 0):

use `/urn:epc:id:sgln:\d+\.\d+\.\d+/`

```js
const texts = [
  "urn:epc:id:sgln:345344423.1345.143", // matched
  "epc:id:sgln:123.456.143",            // not matched
  "urn:epc:id:sgln:3.1.1",              // matched
  "urn:ABC:id:sgln:345344423.1345.143", // not matched
  "urn:epc:id:sgln:345344423.1345",     // not matched
  "urn:epc:id:sgln:2733.34.1"           // matched
];

const re = /urn:epc:id:sgln:\d+\.\d+\.\d+/;


texts.forEach(text => {
  const isMatched = text.match(re);
  console.log( isMatched ? "    matched :" : "not matched :", text);
});
```